# How to get the total length of the records from DBA function?

Tags: php

I just want to know if there are any funcitons that can find the total length of the records the DBA function fetch from the DB file. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Define "length of records" - do you mean the number of rows in a resultset or the byte length of each row, or something else entirely?

Comment: Do you mean the number of rows, or the length of each row or the combined length of all the rows in the resultset?

Comment: yes @Fluffeh and David. I need number of rows. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PDO, you can use get the [number of rows](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) via:

```
<?php
$qry = $dbh->prepare('select * FROM fruit');
$del->execute();
$count = $qry->rowCount();
print("Found $count rows.\n");
?>
```

You can also get the number of rows is you are [using mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) like this:

```
<?php
// yada yada
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Code, Name FROM Country ORDER BY Name");
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);
?>
```

Be aware that this one won't return the number of rows when your query is an insert, delete, update or replace. You would need to use the [affected rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking for, or if you are even using MySql, but if you are, you could try

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS;
```

for all tables, or

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '%sometext%';
```

for tables that contain `sometext` in their names.

For field related details, you could try:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` PROCEDURE ANALYSE();
```